# How can I achieve overlapping card views inside Recycler view?

Tags: java, android

Basically what I need is overlap the views
[View to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hrZB.png)

Each cardview is an item and will be contained within a recyclerview

this is how my card view is defined

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-11dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView...>

    </ScrollView>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_food_little"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And looks like (The blue one is the RelativeLayout):

[How my item card view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGo0K.png)

Please Help

Comment: please post the card view code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the linear layout in the following with cardview and use the resultant layout as the layout for the recyclerview items .

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

</LinearLayout>
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this helps.